# How to use today's date to filter out database results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query (names have been simplified):

```
SELECT A.VAL1, A.VAL2
FROM TABLE1 A, TABLE2 B
WHERE A.VAL2=B.VAL2
AND A.BEGIN_DATE < CURRENT_DATE()
AND A.END_DATE > CURRENT_DATE()
AND B.VAL2=1
```

I get "SQL command not properly ended", however, if I remove lines 4 and 5, it runs perfectly.

What about the two date lines is messing this up?  Thanks for your help

UPDATE**  Sorry.  Yes, this is oracle

Comment: u sure the mysql tag is correct? This error message sounds oracle-ish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use like CURRENT_DATE and not as CURRENT_DATE()

Answer (score 0):

IN MYSQL You have `CURDATE()` for the current date

```
SELECT A.VAL1, A.VAL2
FROM TABLE1 A, TABLE2 B
WHERE A.VAL2=B.VAL2
AND A.BEGIN_DATE < CURDATE()
AND A.END_DATE > CURDATE()
AND B.VAL2=1
```

Comment: This is Oracle OP has updated the question. Also to mark the point that CURDATE() is the synonym of CURRENT_DATE() in MYSQL!